# Как рабоать с localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Закидываю в стор инфу localStorage.setItem('filmId',JSON.stringify(film.id)) таким образом.film.id стринговый. При извлечении появляются доп ковычки.К примеру закидываю "tt21312", а при извлечении получаю ""tt21312""

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties/11233515

Answer (score 1):

Код сохранения/чтения в/из `localStorage` должен быть "зеркальным". Если Вы используете `JSON.stringify` для сохранения, то для чтения надо использовать `JSON.parse`. Но похоже, Вам не нужно ни то, ни другое.

Comment: Если сохранять без JSON.stringify,все ровно остаются лишние ковычки

Comment: @ThenTaXa Нет, не остаются.

Comment: У меня остаются,я пробовал. Он хранится,если открыть в браузере,с кавычками

Comment: @ThenTaXa Вы неправильно пробовали.

Comment: А как тогда правильно?

Comment: А как тогда правильно?

Comment: @ThenTaXa Так, как я написал в ответе.